# Getting all elements from a list of objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I got an object list with some attributes and after populating this list, I want to get all the elements from a specific variable of this object and put it inside a new INT list. I'll try to example:

```
public class Obj1 
{
   public int id {get; set; }
   public string name {get; set; }
   public int? age {get; set; }
}

public List<int> GetAgeList(List<Obj1> list)
{
  List<int> ageList = list.age;//The idea is add all ages into the list..
  return ageList;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward question, with a straightforward answer.. which makes me wonder, what have you tried to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mannimarco is right--you should have provided some of what you have attempted :) There are a number of ways to do this. Maybe you should look up [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) (particularly, the extension method section) and start learning [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594).

Use `.Select()` extension method of the Generic List type. (I'm assuming `obj1` is the same type as `Obj1` and you just made a typo)

```
public List<int> GetAgeList(List<Obj1> list)
{
    return list.Select(o => o.age).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hello, guys, sorry for the lack of information.. I fixed the obj1 to Obj1 tryting to make it clear. Used you suggestion and Its just saying that I need to cast IEnumerable<int?> to List<int>

Comment: @Dan-SP If `Obj1` is exactly as you defined it above, then `age` is not a nullable type. I'm not sure why the compiler would tell you `.ToList()` returns `IEnumerable<int?>`

Comment: Its a nullable type, man, I'll edit it again ! ..Thanks for the help, bro.

Comment: @Dan-SP No problem at all--the better you can describe a problem, the better help you will get on SO :)

Comment: worked perfectly after cast.. Just put: return list.Select(o => (int)o.age).ToList(); since, in this case, I can assure that the age wont be null ( even its being a nullable type). Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main
{
    //Create objects
    Obj1 someObj = new Obj1();
    Obj1 someObj2 = new Obj1();
    Obj1 someObj3 = new Obj1();

    //You should set some values

    //Make a list with them    
    List<Obj1> listSomeObj = new List<Obj1>();

    listSomeObj.Add(someObj);
    listSomeObj.Add(someObj2);
    listSomeObj.Add(someObj3);
}
public class Obj1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

//Here's your function to get that particular value    
public List<int> GetAgeList(List<Obj1> list)
{
    List<int> ageList = new List<int>();
    foreach (Obj1 obj in list)
    {
        ageList.Add(obj.age);
    }
    return ageList;
}
```

This is just an example.